# Accessing Ansible host variables in playbook - error

Tags: ansible

I have a simple ansible playbook with the following data

```
inventory
----------
[admin]
127.0.0.1

[admin:vars]
service_ip=12.1.2.1

[targets]
admin ansible_connection=local

main.yaml
----------
---
- hosts: admin
  roles:
    - admin
  tags: admin

roles/admin/tasks/main.yaml
---------------------------
- debug: msg="{{ service_ip }}"
```

when I run the playbook using the command, ansible-playbook -i inventory main.yaml, I get the following error

```
PLAY [admin] ****************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [admin]

TASK: [admin | debug msg="{{ service_ip }}"] ********************************** 
fatal: [admin] => One or more undefined variables: 'service_ip' is undefined

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/karthi/main.yaml.retry

admin                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is the inclusion of

```
[targets]
admin ansible_connection=local
```

as per the ansible [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html), `You can also select the connection type and user on a per host basis`.

So, changing your inventory file to have

```
[targets]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

should fix the issue

Comment: Thanks that works. What I am trying to do here is run certain tasks in playbook in the localhost  such as generating ssl keys etc. Is this the preferred way to do this ? Also could you explain why ansible_connection=local does not work ?

Comment: Hi @KarthikJ, I've updated the answer to give you a solution more in line with what you're trying to accomplish and an explanation.